# dpdk packet transfer delay , packet loss and retransmission

Tags: dpdk

I see delay in TCP packet transfer  while transferring huge files using SSH/SCP.
The delay is not seen with file sizes up to 35 MB.
Beyond 35 MB there is delay due to TCP out of order /retransmission and packet loss.
For file size 762835531 earlier it took 8 seconds for scp transfer now it takes ~~ 4 mins after DPDK upgrade.
I suspected Small RX and TX queue size on  NICs which are connected to  DPDK is causing packet drops.

1. Increased TX queue and RX queue size as follows.
   RTE_TEST_RX_DESC_DEFAULT 128
   RTE_TEST_TX_DESC_DEFAULT 512

to

RTE_TEST_RX_DESC_DEFAULT 4096
RTE_TEST_TX_DESC_DEFAULT 4096

Saw little improvement.
The time taken for scp reduced to  2mins and 30 seconds for file of size 762835531.

2. Tried to rate limit the TX rate using:
   rte_eth_set_queue_rate_limit API

Not seeing much improvement.

Please suggest ways to configure the mbuf,queue size to optimize the performance and reduce the delay and drop in packet transfer.

Comment: Have you confirmed your guess? Have a look at [rte_eth_stats_get()](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#adec226574c53ae413252c9b15f6f4bab), there is imissed counter to confirm the drops.

Comment: The imissed counter shows 0 but the DPDK core statistics shows TapDroppedPkts : 28.So does it mean Kernel is dropping the packets or DPDK KNI?

Comment: Don't know what TapDroppedPkts counter really is. Also it's not quite clear if you use NICs (as in the original question), TAPs (as in the counter suggests) or KNIs (as in the comment), as those are different types of interfaces with their own nuances. Sorry...

Comment: Andriy,
Sorry.Let me clarify.Below are the statistics of the DPDK counters taken on tap port.
ipackets :1413f
opackets : 271d9
ibytes: 5bfa38
imissed: 0
obytes: e65d138
ierrors:0
oerrors: 0
rx_nombuf: 0
This shows 0 values for imissed , ierrors,oerros and rx_nombuf.
The tcpdump capture(on tap interface) on the sending side shows the lost packet and the same packet is not appearing on the receiving side tcpdump capture which means packet got dropped between tap to kni interface.So where is the packet drop is happening ?Please suggest how to debug this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you have an application which uses Physical DPDK interface and virtual tap interface. On tap interface, you set an IP address for kernel and send `scp` of 35MB file. Is this understanding correct? Id yes, I would suggest trying `example/skeleton` with right arguments to reproduce error. Most likely it would be related to IRQ thread responsible TAP interface.

Comment: @user11221955 are there any updates for me (previous comment)?

Comment: still waitng for the updates from @user11221955